# How to dynamically change database url in birt viewer

Tags: birt

How to change database configuration dynamically. Means can i change database url, username and password according to my requirement in rptlibrary so all rptdesign files will act according to rptlibrary. How can i do this in  my project. Can anybody help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way to change database url is by changing the jndi name of the report according to the parameter or your logic
[View This](http://birtworld.blogspot.in/2007/01/birt-connection-pooling-continued.html)

Comment: Thanks Sundar G for reply

I am trying to do using jndi but i am getting error i cant create datasource itself. When i tested connection i got errors:

org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: The selected driver cannot parse the given JNDI Data Source URL. at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCDriverManager.testConnection(JDBCDriverManager.java:651) at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.util.DriverLoader.testConnection(DriverLoader.java:147) at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.ui.util.DriverLoader.testConnection(DriverLoader.java:175) 

Thanks